# How do I update my family application for a B1/B2?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, application-status

How can I update the application id for my family? I used an unsubmitted application id to schedule an interview for a B1/B2 visa. Now i am unable to retrieve the ones used to schedule the interview. Only the principal applicant id can be updated on the CGI website, but other family members can be updated. If I fill another DS 160 form for them, how do I update it?